# Create Landscape PDF with Pandoc using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: pdf, wkhtmltopdf, pandoc, landscape

I am trying to create PDF with landscape orientation in **Pandoc**.

I am using **WkHtmlToPdf** as a PDF Engine. I chose not to use LaTeX. Here is the command I am using:

> pandoc test.md -t html -o test.pdf

But it creates a portrait orientation. How can I create PDF in landscape mode?

### Things I have tried without success

> pandoc -V geometry:landscape test.md -t html -o test.pdf

> pandoc -O landscape test.md -t html -o test.pdf

Please help.

*Note: I do not want to use LaTeX as my PDF engine.*

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```sh
pandoc test.md -t html \
       --pdf-engine-opt="-O" --pdf-engine-opt="Landscape" \
       -o test.pdf
```

Pandoc doesn't know the `-O` option, it must be given to wkhtmltopdf. Use `--pdf-engine-opts`, once for each option or argument that you want pandoc to pass to the pdf engine.

The above was tested and succeeds on:

```
Ubuntu 20.04
pandoc 2.5
wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: Thank you both persons, perfect editing and commentary!